# Python Watchdog Catch the pid of the file even not only the path

Tags: python, events, filesystemwatcher, python-watchdog

I facing the issue where there are too many file being written, modifed and sometime removed on the system
I was able to log the files and path changed and sort of event logged on them using Python Watchdog llibrary
However, I was unable to catch the process that performed the event

what watchdog offers for an even is `event.is_directory` and `event.src_path` only.

```
def on_deleted(self, event):
    if event.is_directory:
        print(f"[Directory deleted] Path: {event.src_path}")
    else:
        print(f"[File deleted] Path: {event.src_path}")

    process_event(event, 'remove')
```

What I am looking for is something like this

```
def on_deleted(self, event):
    if event.is_directory:
        print(f"[Directory deleted] Path: {event.src_path}")
    else:
        print(f"[File deleted] Path: {event.src_path}")
    
    print(f'The pid of process performing removal is: {event.pid}')
    process_event(event, 'remove')
```

I have tried multiple stuff with watchdog, loggeddfs, inotify and pyinotify but it seems non support this and some were very hard to treat due lack of docs and resources